# $.getScript not working (IE8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I'm loading a script by using $.getScript as seen below.

```
$.getScript('/js/overlay.js', function() {
    alert("TEST");
});
```

In all browsers this is working except from IE. 
IE8 gives me the error that Overlay couldn't be loaded at the line "x". Line "x" looks like:

```
new Overlay();
```

Overlay.js looks like this:

```
var Overlay = function() {
    alert("test");
}
```

Someone familiar with this problem?
I searched google for a answer first but I couldn't find something usefull..

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use ? Where exactly is line X ? in overlay.js too ? Or where ?

Comment: Using jQuery 1.9 line "x" is line 26 but I guess that doesn't really matter. The $.getScript is loaded at line 2. Line 1 is $(document).ready(); Line X isn't in overlay.js but in default.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a problem of asynchronicity :

If the "line x"

```
new Overlay();
```

isn't in the callback you pass to `getScript`, then it is executed before the `Overlay` function is available, apart if you have the `overlay.js` file in cache (and even then, it depends).

Put "line x" in the callback or in a function called from the callback :

```
$.getScript('/js/overlay.js', function() {
    alert("TEST");
    new Overlay();
});
```

Comment: Not working, getting the same error. Now this 2 lines are directly after each other. $.getScript('/js/overlay.js');
            new Overlay();

Comment: Don't put them one after the other. Put `new Overlay();` **inside** the callback (the function you pass to `getScript`).